# Flutter GetX, call a controller method after all widgets has been built

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using `GetX` and I have following codes.

```
RxList<Outlets?> listPharmacyOutlets = <Outlets>[].obs;
RxList listOutletCoordinates = [].obs;

@override
void onInit() async{
  super.onInit();
  await getPharmacyOutlets();
}

Future getPharmacyOutlets() async{
    Map params = {
        //some parameters
    }

    var res = await CommonApiProvider.getPharmacyOutlets(params)
    var outlets = res.data;

    int idx = 0;
    listPharmacyOutlets.clear();
    for(final outlet in outlets){
        listPharmacyOutlets.add(Outlets(
            "latitude": outlet.latitude,
            "longitude": outlet.longitude,
            "pharmacyId": outlet.id,
            "outletName": outlet.name,
            "address": null
        ));

        //now populating address list to fetch addresses for all outlets

        listOutletCoordinates.add({
            "index": idx,
            "latitude": outlet.latitude,
            "longitude": outlet.longitude,
        });

        idx++;
    }

    //I cannot call getOutletAddresses() here because view will not be populated unless this completes.
}

Future getOutletAddresses() async {
    await Future.forEach(listOutletCoordinates, (item) async {
        var result = await CommonApiProvider.getOutletAddresses(item);
        //from result update "address" in "listPharmacyOutlets" by the help of index property in item
    });
}
```

Here is my view.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  child: Column(
      children: List.generate(controller.listPharmacyOutlets.length, (index) {
        var item = controller.listPharmacyOutlets[index];
        return Container(
            child: .......
        );
      })
  ),
);
```

What I want to do is, first method `getPharmacyOutlets()` call only fetches outlets from Rest api and when list of outlets is completed rendering in list,
call `getOutletAddresses()` method to fetch address from google's geocoding  service against the supplied latitude and longitudes. After address has been fetched, i will
update each row in the rendered list of outlets.

I am fetching addresses and outlets separately because I don't want user to wait for all results to come.

Problem, I am not sure when to call `getOutletAddresses()` api so that the addresses are fetched only after outlets has been rendered in the view.

I have in my mind that this could be achieved using `WidgetsBinding` like this.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
       // here call method to fetch address from google service.
    });
```

But I am not sure where to use this because I am using `GetX`, which means all my pages are `stateless`

Any help or any other better Idea will help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to first fill "listOutletCoordinates" and then want to call method "getOutletAddresses" ?

Comment: Nope first I want to get list of outlets, render the listview, then get addresses from coordinates and update the listview.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use the `worker functions` provided by getx controller like:

- [ever](https://pub.dev/documentation/get_rx/latest/get_rx/ever.html) -  is called every time the Rx variable emits a new value.
- [everAll](https://pub.dev/documentation/get_rx/latest/get_rx/everAll.html) - Much like `ever` , but it takes a `List` of *Rx* values Called every time its variable is changed. That's it.
- [once](https://pub.dev/documentation/get_rx/latest/get_rx/once.html) - is called only the first time the variable has been changed.

For the present situation,

- You can use `once` or `ever`and based on the required condition you can then call your desired function
- So the best time to call the `getOutletAddresses()` function is after `listOutletCoordinates` is filled .

And in my opinion it's not about the view rendering and then calling a function. Instead its to focus on the data being fetched sequentially. Because the View updation is taken care by `Getx Builder` or `Obx()` provided by `Getx` once the data is properly fetched

If using `ever`:

```
ever(listOutletCoordinates,(value){
  // Based on the value you can call the getOutletAdresses() function
});
```

But with `once` you get more flexibility , Use something like:

```
once(listOutletCoordinates,(value){
  // Based on the value you can call the getOutletAdresses() function
},condition:() => listOutletCoordinates.isNotEmpty);
```

**Alternatively**:

You can use `listen` property to call function based on listening value.

Example:

```
listOutletCoordinates.listen((val){
     // Based on the value you can call the getOutletAdresses() function
});
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly where in my above code, shall I use worker function, or  run `listOutletCoordinates.listen...`

Comment: You can use it within onInit() or onReady() functions, for your code use inside onInit() function

Comment: i added to `onInit` function `await getPharmacyOutlets();`

`listAddresses.listen((val) {
     print(val);
});` but didnt work

Comment: Add inside the constructor of the build method, like `ControllerName instance = Get.find()`; then for listening `instance.listOutletCoordinates.listen((val){print(val)});`

Comment: And in the question ,there is no mention of `listenAddresses` , just make sure that `listenAddresses ` is observable value i.e `.obs` value.

Comment: If above still doesn't work, I have updated my answer to include examples with `ever` and `once` I personally prefer you use `once` as it suits to your problem . Hope it helps !